# VB.NET How do I check the size and dimensions of an image?

Tags: vb.net

I'm reading in an image (jpg) using the code below and I need to check that the image is no bigger than 150 pixels by 150 pixels and is less than 25k, how should I do this?

```
PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(.FileName)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
If New FileInfo(.FileName).Length > 25 * 1024 Then ... 'More than 25KB'
Dim img = Image.FromFile(.FileName)
If img.Size.Width > 150 OrElse img.Size.Height > 150 Then ... 'More than 150x150'
Picturebox1.Image = img
```